# How can I automatically arrange windows in Windows 10 to have three columns in ultrawide displays?

Tags: windows-10

There are ultrawide (28", 3840 x 1600) which are suited to be used with three windows.

Besides maximising each one of them vertically and manually arranging them in three columns, is there a way in Windows 10 to automatically tile them side by side? Like the current left/right automatic arrangement of Windows 10, but automatic and for three windows.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One option is to use Windows [Powertoys](https://github.com/microsoft/PowerToys), more specifically, [FancyZones](https://github.com/microsoft/PowerToys/wiki/FancyZones-Overview)

[image]

Further solutions are listed in https://www.geckoandfly.com/26633/split-monitor-screen-windows-macos/